# jquery how to iterate over nested element and get their value

Tags: jquery

I have `div` inside which I have several `form`. I need to iterate over each form and get values from it. For debug I try the following

```
$(document).on('submit', '.submit_button', function() {
    $('#days_payment').children('form').each(function () {
        console.log(this);
    });
  });
```

But it doesnt work, page reloads and nothing get printed to console.

How to make correct loop ?

Comment: You need to stop your form from being submitted

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the submit from occurring, return false in your function after the logging:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.submit_button', function() {
    $('#days_payment').children('form').each(function () {
        console.log(this);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't capturing any of the passed values (e.g. index and value) in the callback function for your `.each`.

Change it slightly to:

```
$('#days_payment').children('form').each(function(indx, el) {
  console.log(el.value)
})
```

Assuming your DOM traversal is correct, that'll log the values of each element within your `form`.

You may also want to prevent the default submission action from the event being launched so add this as well:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.submit_button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  //...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent form submission.

```
  $(document).on('submit', '.submit_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDeault();
    $('#days_payment').children('form').each(function () {
        console.log(this);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMl :

```
<div   id="days_payment" >
        <form action="/" method="post" name="form1">
            <input type="text"  name="inp1" value="V1" />
            <button id="sub1" class="submitButton">sub1</button>
        </form>
        <form action="/" method="post" name="form2">
            <input type="text" name="inp2" value="V2" />
            <button id="sub2" class="submitButton">sub2</button>
        </form>
        <form action="/" method="post" name="form3">
            <input type="text" name="inp3" value="V3" />
            <button id="sub3" class="submitButton">sub3</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".submitButton").on("click", function () {
                $("#days_payment form").each(function () {
                    $(this).children("input").each(function () {
                        console.log($(this).val());
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```